# How do I ensure that a AnimationController is called even in another route?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this code currently, which works just fine.

It controls a timer which, when it hits zero will change the mode from `EATING -> FASTING -> READY`.
However, if the user goes to another route (using `Navigator.push`), the mode won't switch until the user comes back to the page with the timer on it. What is the best way to resolve this?

```dart
controller = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 10));
//...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the standard `TickerProvider`, i.e. a `State` mixin, which you are probably mixing in using [`with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleTickerProviderStateMixin-mixin.html).

This ticker provider actually performs a really important action of **muting** the ticker when you are in another route.
Having said that, you apparently want to avoid this behavior, which can be achieved by creating your own `TickerProvider`, similar to how [`TestVSync`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/TestVSync-class.html) does it.

For this, I created a simple [`mixin`](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#adding-features-to-a-class-mixins) called `NonStopTickerProviderMixin`:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';

mixin NonStopTickerProviderMixin implements TickerProvider {
  @override
  Ticker createTicker(TickerCallback onTick) => Ticker(onTick);
}
```

If you want to use it, add `with NonStopTickerProviderMixin` to your `State` instead of `SingleTickerProviderStateMixin` and you are good to go.

Full working code [as a Gist](https://gist.github.com/creativecreatorormaybenot/d23bf64984dd55f2b134e0b5f77a7a34).

### Notes

There is not really a point in making the class I created as `mixin`. It should really be `class` and that works just fine as well with the `with` keyword, however, I wanted it to be a replacement of [`(Single)TickerProviderStateMixin`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/37e25238a8677d44dea058032173a8c00baec7d5/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/ticker_provider.dart#L77).
The reason the original ticker provider implementation that is used for `State`'s is a `mixin` is simply that it uses the `didChangeDependencies` and `dispose` methods from `State` firstly, to perform the muting of the `Ticker` and secondly, to add some safety assertions.
If you want to add them, you can just copy them from the source code I linked and add `on State` to your `mixin` (but do not add the **muting** part as this is exactly what you want to avoid).

Comment: thanks so much, it works! just one thing i wanted to clarify - you said "This ticker provider actually performs a really important action of pausing the ticker when you are in another route." but in fact the ticker would seem to keep ticking but just not perform the listening part. if I navigated away with 8 seconds left on the timer, and waited 10 seconds and came back, it would immediately transition (i.e. it had reached 0).

Comment: maybe it's because i passed controller to the route?

Comment: @MattTakao You are correct. The default `Ticker` is only [muted](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/scheduler/Ticker/muted.html) when in another route, which means that the `Duration` will still advance in the background. You could circumvent this (if you did not want the `NonStopTickerProvider` but just something that **pauses** when navigating) by storing the animation value in your `State` and then adding something like `if (TickerMode.of(context)) animationController.value = storedAnimationValue;` to your `didChangeDependencies` method.